# Gdb Syntax for print command

Tags: printing, syntax, gdb, command

How can I view the data at the address of the first operand in gdb?

```
cmp [ebp+eax], edi
```

I tried using:

```
print /d $ebp
print /d $eax
```

and manually adding the values to make the address, but was not sure what to do next, or if there was an easier way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(gdb) help x
Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS.
ADDRESS is an expression for the memory address to examine.
FMT is a repeat count followed by a format letter and a size letter.
Format letters are o(octal), x(hex), d(decimal), u(unsigned decimal),
  t(binary), f(float), a(address), i(instruction), c(char) and s(string).
Size letters are b(byte), h(halfword), w(word), g(giant, 8 bytes).
The specified number of objects of the specified size are printed
according to the format.
```

For your example:

```
x/d $ebp+$eax
```

Comment: thanks, it was that second dollar sign I was missing from x/d $ebp+eax